# Block web access to a single subfolder using IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-8, requestfiltering

I want to block access from the web to the `logs` subfolder on a website. The following `web.config` seems to work...

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
               <hiddenSegments>
                   <add segment="logs" />
               </hiddenSegments>
           </requestFiltering>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

...but it will also block access to any `logs` folder in all subfolders (`foo/logs`, `foo/bar/logs`, etc.).

How can I block only the `logs` folder that is in the same folder as the `web.config` file?

I know I can put a `web.config` file directly in the `logs` directory, but that is not an option here because it will most likely get wiped by accident when someone wipes the log files.

Comment: Use URL Rewrite module to redirect unwanted requests to an error page, or simply abort them.

Answer (score 1):

You could iis url rewrite rule to block the request for a particular folder.

below is the rule:

```
  <rule name="RequestBlockingRule16" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/s2/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
            </rule>
```

[image]

[image]

folder structure:

[image]

[image]

s1 is the site root folder.